# What software can extract block diagrams from pdf?

Tags: software, bibliometrics

I am looking for ways to extract block diagrams systematically from a folder of pdfs so that I can compare them quickly. I tried [pyMuPDF](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/725) but it does not exactly extract figures but all the bitmaps in the figures instead. And it omits more semantically meaningful figures like block diagrams.

I found at least one Chinese literature reading [site](https://readpaper.com/paper/2950734558)  manages to do that. But it only limits to some papers. I wonder how they do that also.

Comment: Reminder that software recommendations are generally [on topic](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/what-are-the-limits-of-shopping-questions-when-it-comes-to-software), so long as the request is sufficiently tied to academia as a whole.

Comment: There are multiple ways to store a diagram in a PDF file, some of which will not be easy to extract.

Comment: Note that there are some things that the authors of the PDF can do to make it hard to get stuff out. Usually not impossible, just annoying.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of tools to bulk extract images from PDFs, some common ones are listed [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Extracting_images_from_PDF). However, it should be noted that like Anonymous Physicist said, diagrams are not always stored as images, and this makes the whole affair nightmarishly complicated. While I do not know if an off-the-shelf solution for this problem exists, [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-drawing-and-graphics.html) (the last example on this page) might have something close to the functionality you are seeking. But I am afraid getting clean and consistent results for all the possible PDF documents would be very hard.